# pagina PHP dentro de uma pagina PHP

Tags: php

Fala pessoal, então o meu problema é o seguinte, eu tenho uma pagina PHP que é o meu formulario e tenho uma pagina PHP pra receber as informações do formulario e dar a resposta ao usuario, coisa bem simples. Mas eu queria que a resposta ao usuario fosse dentro da pagina do formulario, que quando ele envie o formulario, apareça dentro de uma tabela dentro da mesma pagina do formulario, como faço isso?

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title>lista de tarefas</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form>
       <table id="tab"> 
    <?php
        $dat=isset($_GET["data"])?$_GET["data"]:"15/10/2019";
        $tar=isset($_GET["tarefa"])?$_GET:"não informado";
        $tab=$_GET["tab"];
        
        echo "<tr><td>$tar</td><td>até $dat</td></tr>";
         
    ?>
        </table>   
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>cadastro de tarefas</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="GET" action="form.php">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Crie Sua tarefa</legend>
    <p><label>tarefa</label>    : <input type="text" name="tarefa" ></p>
    <p><label>conclusão</label> : <input type="date" name="data"></p>
  </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Há várias formas de se fazer isso. 
A primeria (de que mais gosto) e várias empresas usam é usando **XML HttpRequest**
:https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp. Usando essa técnica, é possível, por exemplo, fazer a requisição sem mesmo atualizar toda a página (o famoso AJAX).

> *AJAX é o sonho de um desenvolvedor, porque você pode:*
>
> - Ler dados de um servidor Web - depois que a página foi carregada
> - Atualize uma página da Web sem recarregá-la
> - Envie dados para um servidor Web - em segundo plano

Vou fazer um exemplo bem simples para que você tenha conhecimento de como funciona.

> **index.php:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>cadastro de tarefas</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="GET" action="other-form.php">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Crie Sua tarefa</legend>
            <p><label>tarefa</label> : <input type="text" name="tarefa" autofocus></p>
            <p><label>conclusão</label> : <input type="date" name="data"></p>
            <!-- <p><label>conclusão</label> : <input type="text" name="tab"></p> -->
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        <div id="result"></div>

    </form>

    <script>
        //Usando Javascript
        function loadDoc(data) {
            //Isso é AJaxa ()
            //AJAX = Assíncrono Javascript XML.
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("POST", "other-form.php", true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhttp.send(data);
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].onsubmit = function() {
            let tarefa = this.elements.tarefa.value;
            let data = this.elements.data.value;
            loadDoc(`tarefa=${tarefa}&data=${data}`);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

> Segundo Arquivo:

`other-form.php`

```php
<table id="tab" border>
    <?php

    $dat = isset($_POST["data"]) ? $_POST["data"] : "15/10/2019";

    $tar = isset($_POST["tarefa"]) ? $_POST['tarefa'] : "não informado";
    // $tab=$_GET["tab"];

    echo "<tr><td>$tar</td><td>até $dat</td></tr>";

    ?>
</table>
```

**REFERÊNCIA:**
1. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp
2. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

Comment: Verei a respeito sobre o AJAX, mas consegui resolver ,não sei se da forma correta. Mudei para o method POST e apaguei o action e agora está dando o resultado que eu queria, mais gostei do AJAX, vou tentar incluir no projeto. Obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente que para enviar os dados para outra página você usava o metodo `POST`, além de que você não precisa do código HTML no outro arquivo, você precisa apenas receber e tratar os dados da forma que você deseja ( não sei o que você vai querer fazer pois não colocou na pergunta ) e apenas redirecionar o usuário para seu `index` e apresentar uma mensagem de erro ou sucesso, para isso você pode usar as `$_SESSION` do PHP e obviamente um `header("Location: ")` no final para redirecionar a sua página. Pode olhar aqui para saber mais a respeito: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php . Outra opção, como o Taffarel comentou ai, é utilizar o XML HttpRequest, mas que é mais usado em forma do AJAX juntamente ao jQuery hoje em dia, pode olhar aqui para saber mais a respeito também: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp .

Comment: consegui resolver! não sei se da forma correta, mudei pro method POST, e apaguei a Action do form. e está fazendo o que eu quero, porém vi um pouco agora no youtube sobre o AJAX e achei interessante, vou tentar fazer com ele, Obrigado!!